# Math.random won't compile in jGrasp

Tags: java, math, random, compiler-errors, symbols

When I try to use the Math.random in a code I get  "error: Cannot find symbol" and points to the "." between Math and random. However when I rewrite the code into an online compiler on programiz.com it works without a problem. This is the code I have.

```
public class RandomMath {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   
   int firstNum = 1;
   int lastNum = 3;
   
   // generates a random number between 0 to 1
   System.out.println(firstNum + Math.random()); 

   }
}
```

I tried writing the code with out anything else, just the Math.random alone. it still says the "." is a symbol that can't be found.

Comment: You shouldn't have to explicitly import Math because it's part of the java.lang package, but since this code fails in JGrasp, I'm guessing that you're experiencing a JGrasp specific bug (the code worked fine for me using OpenJDK and Atom editor). Although I have no solution for you, I have a workaround: wherever you call `Math.random()`, instead use the fully qualified name, `java.lang.Math.random()`. I would also encourage you to file a bug against JGrasp, but they don't seem to have a publicly visible bugbase or even a user forum.

Comment: I using Java 8, and I didn't see any error messages

Comment: Post the ***exact*** error jGRASP gave you. Specifically, edit it into your post.

Comment: Although we don't have a publicly-visible bug database or forum, we do respond quickly to bug reports - usually the same day, even for ones that appear to be user error. There is a "Report a Bug" feature on jGRASP itself, as well as automatic reporting (with user approval) of uncaught exceptions. If there are issues that are affecting a lot of users (virus scanner false positives, bugs in new Java releases, etc.) we'll usually note those on our main web page.

Comment: @davidalayachew. here is the error code I recieved. I created a new file with a new name because my professor sad it was because my file name was Math and that was causing the problem.                                                                           
----jGRASP exec: javac -g hilo.java
hilo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
      System.out.println(Math.random());
                             ^
  symbol:   method random()
  location: class Math
1 error

 ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Comment: If you still have the old Math.class file in that directory, you need to delete it.

Comment: @ghostsushi I also strongly suspect that there is a .class file for `Math` somewhere. Try and find it, then delete it. You can get an idea of where it is by going to `Settings`, then checking the box that says `Verbose Messages`. Then, try compiling again. The new message will tell you exactly where in your computer that command is running. Then, you just need to check those areas to see if that sneaky Math.class file is there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have your own class named "Math" in the same directory, so any unqualified reference to "Math" is a reference to that class. It's generally a bad idea to name your own classes the same as frequently-used JDK classes, but if you do then you can fully qualify as suggested above "java.lang.Math.random()" or you can import java.lang.Math (but if you do the latter and your own "Math" class is in the default package, there will be no way to access your own "Math" class if you need to).

Also, the javac error will have a caret ^ pointing to the dot, but below that you should see "symbol:   method random()".